# Is there a canonical way to get which version of e2fsprogs you have installed?

Tags: version, e2fsprogs

[Linuxtopia's Kernel Configuration book](https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_kernel/kernel_configuration/ch03s02.html) recommends the following:

> To determine which version of e2fsprogs you have on your system, run the following command:
>   `$ tune2fs`

This seems kind of funky, though.

Does e2fsprogs have a canonical way to check the version, or is that as good as it gets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the common way, a potential problem is that the binaries are in `/sbin` and not all users may be able to run them.

I checked a couple of projects that were likely candidate to use (parts of) `e2fsprogs`, like `gparted` - at best they really only care about the presence of `libuuid` and don't have any autoconf detection of `e2fsprogs`, or its version.

The `libext2fs` library exports the function `ext2fs_get_library_version()`, so to do this robustly:

```
/* gcc -lext2fs -o gete2ver gete2ver.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ext2fs/ext2fs.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char *e2ver, *e2date;
    int ver;

    ver=ext2fs_get_library_version(&e2ver,&e2date);
    printf("version=%04i %s %s\n",ver,e2ver,e2date);
    return 0;
}
```

Other options:

1. `e2fsprogs` comes with a set of libraries, so you can use `pkg-config`, e.g.

   `pkg-config --modversion ext2fs`

   `pkg-config --modversion e2p`

   (But, some distros may not install enough "developer" material by default)
2. The translated message catalogues [contain metadata](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/msginit-Invocation.html#msginit-Invocation) in the empty "" msgid:

   `LANG=fr_FR gettext e2fsprogs ""`

   (But, there's no guarantee any particular language will be installed)

Answer (score 4):

`tune2fs` is one of the few e2fsprogs programs which prints its version and exits when given nothing to do (the others are `dumpe2fs` and `resize2fs`), and it’s been part of e2fsprogs for a very long time (probably since the beginning). It is therefore a reliable way of determining the installed version of e2fsprogs.

There’s no “official” description of how to determine the installed version of e2fsprogs in its documentation, as far as I can determine.

Answer (score 1):

It does seem kind of funky. If you don't like remembering to use `tune2fs`, you could instead check the `e2fsprogs` package you installed.

If you installed it from source code, you can probably check the source very easily.  (The version number in the tarball name, or a NEWS / Changelog file).

If you installed it from a distribution package, there are some nice commands for this.  It depends exactly how your distribution is set up:

```
# Debian / Ubuntu
dpkg -l e2fsprogs

# alternatively
sudo which mkfs.ext4
dpkg -S /sbin/mkfs.ext4

# Fedora
rpm -q e2fsprogs

# alternatively
which mkfs.ext4
rpm -q --whatprovides /usr/sbin/mkfs.ext4

# ...
```